# Trigger an update to all entries from database via phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a WordPress website that sore entries via a form.

On that form I've add a new field with Yes as default value.

I have over 50K entries created by users so I need to trigger an update to all entries from database.

It is possible to be triggered an update to all entries from database via phpMyAdmin or any other solution?

Comment: You could just run a quick query... `UPDATE table SET NewCol = 'Y' WHERE NewCol is NULL` for example

Comment: Right. Make sure you have a backup of your database first, in case you fat-finger something.